# configure magento database connection to connect to other PC on same LAN (team members work in one database)

Tags: magento-1.9, database

how to

> configure magento  database connection

to connect to other PC on same LAN (team members work in one database which on PC in our LAN )

i'm new to magento and i searched for that but nothing lead me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into your local.xml file, this should be under `app/etc/local.xml`. This will have your database connection information. When setting up a db connection you can specify a lot of information but I guess the really important part for you will be the `host` node.

If you have already installed Magento on your local machine then you could update this file. If not then you should be able to setup your database connection via the setup configuration.

Comment: so how can i dump connection information ??

Comment: @MohamedAbdelrahman I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: i want to see what connection string data is ??
hostname, username ...etc 

how can i see this information from controller (dump them)

Comment: @MohamedAbdelrahman you can simply look into the Magento instance's local.xml if you access to the server.